# Titanium SOAP Call ActionNotSupported using suds.js

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, titanium-mobile

I have `http://192.168.15.45:8081/Taqeem.CRM.Appointments.Service.svc?wsdl` service and method BookAppointment and I have also mentioned the parameters in the code and it is values.

```
var url = "http://192.168.15.45:8081/Taqeem.CRM.Appointments.Service.svc?wsdl";
var callparams = {
    AppointmentNumber: 'APP-00000003-H042S5',
    UserId: '4'
};

var suds = new SudsClient({
    endpoint: url,
    targetNamespace: 'http://tempuri.org'
});

try {
    suds.invoke('BookAppointment', {}, function(xmlDoc) {
        var ManifestXML = this.responseText;
        console.log(ManifestXML);
        var results = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('ResultCode').text;
        console.log('result'+ results);
        if (results && results.length>0) {
            var result = results.item(0);
            label.text = '1 Euro buys you ' + results.item(0).text + ' U.S. Dollars.';
        } else {
            label.text = 'Oops, could not determine result of SOAP call.';
        }
    });
} catch(e) {
    Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e);
}
```

I've used the suds.js and when I execute the below code. I get the error as ActionNotSupport

Complete response:

```
[INFO] :   <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
    a:ActionNotSupported
    </faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
    The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/BookAppointment' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
    </faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

I feel like I'm passing the wrong TargetNameSpace but I have checked in `http://192.168.15.45:8081/Taqeem.CRM.Appointments.Service.svc?wsdl` and its good. I request to check the above link for list of methods.

I've used the SOAP UI and it is executing perfect. I get the perfect response.

Comment: Did you try http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Dealing_with_SOAP_Web_Services

Comment: Yes I tried without luck, and in that guide it is also recommended to not to use soap call??? Why?

Comment: Actually the same thing happened to me and I ended up using php to handle soap calls, put the php script on my server, then call the php script url with parameters from titanium. At least this way you can save time instead of keep on trying to do it using titanium. If you need help writing the php script I can help you, for that you need a host server and php with soap enabled.